# Ошибка Operation timed out в curl

Tags: php, curl

При запуске php скрипта возникает ошибка Operation timed out after 120000 millisec with 0 bytes received; как ее исправить?

Comment: не отвечает видимо тот ресурс, к которому вы обращаетесь, можно конечно увеличить время ожидания, но смысл?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
```

или сделай хедер без gzip - 'accept-encoding: deflate, br'

Comment: Не помогло, та же ошибка

Comment: @JohnFranklin ну тогда код curl в студию и url с которым ошибка возникает